# com.google.ar.core.Session.createAnchor(com.google.ar.core.Pose)' on a null object reference

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality

I want to draw 3d object on the air ( front of camera view ) without detecting the a surface  and it should be automatically place without click event . Therefore I make a demo app. but while app run it get an error that "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.ar.core.Anchor com.google.ar.core.Session.createAnchor(com.google.ar.core.Pose)' on a null object reference". how can I fix this. if my demo code totally wrong , how can I manage My requirement

.So I want to put 3d object on the air without any click event and without detecting a surface .

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ModelRenderable modelRenderable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        setUpModel();
        try {
            setUpPlane();
        } catch (UnavailableDeviceNotCompatibleException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnavailableSdkTooOldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnavailableApkTooOldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void setUpModel() {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, R.raw.wolves)

                .build()
                .thenAccept(renderable -> modelRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Model can't be Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return null;
                });
    }

    private void setUpPlane() throws UnavailableDeviceNotCompatibleException, UnavailableSdkTooOldException, UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException, UnavailableApkTooOldException {
 /*       arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(new BaseArFragment.OnTapArPlaneListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTapPlane(HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
                createModel(anchorNode);
            }
        });*/

        float[] position = { 0, 0, (float) -2.2};      //  { x, y, z } position
        float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };      //  { x, y, z, w } quaternion rotation
        Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
        Anchor myAnchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));


        Pose mCameraRelativePose=Pose.makeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f);
        session.createAnchor(mCameraRelativePose);
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(myAnchor);
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        createModel(anchorNode);

    }

    private void createModel(AnchorNode anchorNode){
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setOnTouchListener(new Node.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(0.5f);
        node.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.01f);
        node.select();


    }
}
`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.